# Prove that a subset of $\Bbb R$ is equinumerous to $\Bbb R$ using Schröder–Bernstein thorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Math 3345 Section 16 Exercise 14

**Let A be a subset of $\Bbb R$ which contains a non-degenerate interval I. Prove that A is equinumerous to $\Bbb R$ (Hint: use Schröder–Bernstein theorem.)**
Here's what I have so far. *Note: I'm using the overline (example: $\overline A$) to denote cardinality*

I *believe* that we are looking to show $\overline A = \overline {\Bbb R}$ by showing that there is a bijection $f :A \rightarrow \Bbb R$?

Since $A \subseteq {\Bbb R}$, then $\overline A \le \overline {\Bbb R}$, thus there exists an injection from A to $\Bbb R$.

I'm unsure as to how to proceed. Should I continue by looking to prove that $\overline {\Bbb R} \le \overline A$, and thus there exists a bijection from A to ${\Bbb R}$ and  $\overline A = \overline {\Bbb R}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, in order to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, you would need to prove $|\mathbb R|\le |A|$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm would it be appropriate to choose I = (0,1) and prove it is equinumerous to $\Bbb R$? Then $\Bbb R$ is equinumerous to $I \subseteq A$, thus |$\Bbb R$| $\le$ A?

Comment: x @Drag, you don't get to choose what $I$ is; you just know that there is some $I$ that's a subset of $A$. But any proof that works rof $(0,1)$ would be easy to adapt to working with an arbitrary interval.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Think about what kinds of functions are defined on an interval and have vertical asymptotes that fly off to positive or negative infinity, like arctangent. If you can figure out an injection from ${\mathbb R}$ to any one non-degenerate interval, then you can use any non-degenerate interval by coming up with a bijection between two arbitrary non-degenerate intervals (think stretch and shift).